# toString override formatting with specific tabbing using StringBuilder

Tags: java, formatting, tostring

Here is my Java coding attempt at overriding the toString to format output neatly.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(getEmpID())
.append(getLastName())
.append(getFirstName())
.append(getHours())
.append(getRate())
.append(getGross());

return String.format("%-58", sb.toString());
```

Here is what output should look like:

```
42345 Bruch      Max             40.00    21.50 $  860.00 

23456 Elgar      Eddie           43.00    20.00 $  890.00 

34567 Bach       John            30.00    30.00 $  900.00 

12345 Wagner     Rick            41.00    30.00 $ 1245.00 

88888 Mozart     Wolfie          36.00    40.00 $ 1440.00 

65432 Chopin     Fred            45.00    23.25 $ 1104.38 

72345 Strauss    Butch           50.00    25.00 $ 1375.00
```

---

My Question is: Is there a way to put, in the return statement, \t tab for specific appends?

for example the hours worked is tabbed over much farther than the first name compared to the last name.

I'm not sure if the "%-58" is going to evenly space the output the way I want it to.

Comment: Have you tried `append("\t")` between each append?

Comment: Which Strauss is "Butch"?

Comment: @ajb: don't tell me you don't know Butch Strauss? He's Richard's redneck brother.

Comment: Ah, yes, the one who wrote the opera "Salami".  I remember now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap the StringBuilder in a Formatter, and use a format String to add all the fields in at once.

For example...

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  Formatter formatter = new Formatter(stringBuilder);

  String template = "%-7s %-15s %-15s %-35.2f %-5.2f $ %-8.2f"; // a rough guess!
  formatter.format(template, getEmpID(), getLastName(), getFirstName(), 
            getHours(), getRate(), getGross());
  return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

You could put `\t` in the template String as well, but I find it more logical *and safer* to just use numbers with format specifiers. Tabs can fail if there's a significant variation in the length of Strings of a single property. These numbers can even be variables that hold numbers that are then converted to a String representation in the template String.

The code and numbers are just a rough estimate and will have to change, but hopefully you get the idea.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> This one looks like it will work for pretty much any length of entry in all categories, however could you explain to me what Formatter is doing? is it just replacing the String.format call in my return statement?

Yes, in fact `String.format(...)` likely uses a java.util.Formatter object behind the scenes. Please check out the API for details. By using a single template String to gather all of the data together, you can give each property its own format size, precision and specifier.

For example:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.List;

public class FormatExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<FormatExData> data = new ArrayList<>();
      data.add(new FormatExData("42345", "Max", "Bruch", 40, 21.5));
      data.add(new FormatExData("23456", "Eddie", "Elgar", 43, 20));
      data.add(new FormatExData("1111", "John", "Bach", 30, 30));
      data.add(new FormatExData("00001", "Donald", "Duck", 50, 40));
      data.add(new FormatExData("99999", "Mickey", "Mouse", 20, 15));
      data.add(new FormatExData("666", "Satan", "Mephistopheles", 100, 100));

      for (FormatExData datum : data) {
         System.out.println(datum);
      }
   }
}

class FormatExData {
   private String id;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private double hours;
   private double rate;

   public FormatExData(String id, String firstName, String lastName,
         double hours, double rate) {
      this.id = id;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.hours = hours;
      this.rate = rate;
   }

   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }

   public double getHours() {
      return hours;
   }

   public double getRate() {
      return rate;
   }

   public double getGross() {
      return hours * rate;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      Formatter formatter = new Formatter(stringBuilder);
      String template = "%-7s %-15s %-10s %10.2f %10.2f %11s";
      formatter.format(template, getId(), getLastName(), getFirstName(),
            getHours(), getRate(), currencyFormat.format(getGross()));
      formatter.close();
      return stringBuilder.toString();
   }

}
```

Which would return:

```
42345   Bruch           Max             40.00      21.50     $860.00
23456   Elgar           Eddie           43.00      20.00     $860.00
1111    Bach            John            30.00      30.00     $900.00
00001   Duck            Donald          50.00      40.00   $2,000.00
99999   Mouse           Mickey          20.00      15.00     $300.00
666     Mephistopheles  Satan          100.00     100.00  $10,000.00
```

Comment: right now that I read your answer, is so much cleaner than mine hahaha, looks nice.

Comment: This one looks like it will work for pretty much any length of entry in all categories, however could you explain to me what Formatter is doing? is it just replacing the String.format call in my return statement?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it just concatenating the tabs, so it would be something like:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    String sb = getEmpID() + "\t" + getLastName() + "\t\t" +
                getFirstName() + "\t\t\t" + getHours() + "\t" +
                getRate() + "\t" + getGross());

    return sb;
}
```

I know is not that clean, but it should work.

Comment: This will fail if any of the Strings returned from a particular field have a wide variety of lengths.

Comment: true, although a 'firstName' field should be limited, am I right? It's just a matter of finding the right amount of tabs to concatenate.

Comment: No, using more tabs will not work. If the variance between the largest String and the smallest String of any single property is >= tab width, your suggestion will fail regardless of the number of tabs used.